# how to optimise double dereferencing?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, optimization, sse, avx

Very specific optimisation task. 
I have 3 arrays:

- const char* inputTape
- const int* inputOffset, organised in a group of four
- char* outputTapeoutput

which i must assemble output tape from input, according to following 5 operations:

```
int selectorOffset = inputOffset[4*i];
char selectorValue = inputTape[selectorOffset];
int outputOffset = inputOffset[4*i+1+selectorValue];
char outputValue = inputTape[outputOffset];
outputTape[i] = outputValue; // store byte
```

and then advance counter.

All iterations are same and could be done all in parallel. Format of inputOffset could be a subject for change, but until same input will produce same output.

OpenCL on GPU fails on this algorithm (works same or even slower that cpu)

Assembly the best i got 5 mov, 1 lea, 1 dec instructions. Upd:
thanks to  Peter Cordes little hint

```
loop_start:
mov         eax,dword ptr [rdx-10h]             ; selector offset
movzx       r10d,byte ptr [rax+r8]          ; selector value
mov         eax,dword ptr [rdx+r10*4-0Ch]       ; output offset
movzx       r10d,byte ptr [r8+rax]          ; output value
mov         byte ptr [r9+rcx-1],r10b            ; store to outputTape
lea         rdx, [rdx-10h]                  ; pointer to inputOffset for current 
dec         ecx                             ; loop counter, sets zero flag if (ecx == 0)
jne         loop_start                      ; continue looping while non zero iterations left: ( ecx != 0 )
```

How could i optimise this for SSE/AVX operation? i am stumbled...

UPD: better to see it than to hear it..
[image]

Comment: Can you show some example and whole processing (final goal), I'm sort of lost in the shortened C explanation, it looks like it is hard-railed to your original idea... Is it about mixing 4 different streams into one output? Then I would rather suggest to read all 4 streams at the same time (with the same target dword) and write whole dword... if that is possible (i.e. `inputOffset` array evolves in a way where continuous mixing is possible). If you would prepare some example of the arrays with non-trivial but short case, it would be easier to say what you want as result.

Comment: Also if the arrays are long enough, this may greatly benefit from 4 parallel threads, you just must make sure they will be enough far apart from each (64B at least in theory, practically more like 10kB, or if you can run the task in batches then each thread processing one task behind the other, to avoid any collisions), to avoid cache line collisions upon writing. ... reading through your description again, ok, it's not trivial to mix this... Maybe I would even consider if there's any chance to redesign the thing which feeds the data into this, or the consumer thing, to change structures.

Comment: Ped7g, its a ternary logic gates simulator. ternary muxer has 4 inputs. first selector input, that trit selects which of three rest inputs to provide on the output.. one trit is coded by 1 byte, each byte can be 0, 1, 2. given inputTape, you should provide its outputs to outputTape. each 4 inputIndex codes 1 ternary muxer, althought its structure is a subject to change is you could came up with a better idea. I shown my implementation and asked for optimisation

Comment: so if the muxer[i] is like [12, 34, 55, 66] (all 0..255 values?) and inputTape[12] is 1 (must be 0..2 value), then outputTape[i] = inputTape[55] ? ... how many muxers, sounds to me like you can easily split this into parallel threads each producing different segment of outputTape, sharing only inputTape data... Also I think there may be some sse/avx shuffling possible, but you should provide some better example of possible non-trivial data to see how the reads/writes can be grouped/vectorized.

Comment: Ped7g, outputTape[i] = inputTape[ muxer[ i+inputTape[ muxer[i] ]+1 ] ] where i =0...

Comment: Ped7g, ofc it is in parallel, different segments, so on.. question is not parallelisation. question is how to convert loop to SSE/AVX?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163608/discussion-between-xakepp35-and-ped7g).

Comment: Put the `dec` next to the `jne` at the bottom of the loop, so it can macro-fuse on Sandybridge-family CPUs.  Your loop is probably not bottlenecked on uop throughtput, so this might not help, though.  (And it would mean changing the addressing mode in the store to `[r9+rcx-1]`, but that's fine).  Also, `sub rdx, 10h` would be no worse than `lea`.  I guess you do need both counters, though, because an addressing mode can only scale by up to 8, not 16.

Comment: Peter Cordes, so there is nothing to do more to optimise and sse/avx is not even possible for MOVs like this?

Comment: Peter Cordes, sub  rdx, 10h could affect flags, so its possibly more heavyweight cpu implementation for signed operations. in theory. LEA does not modifies flags and M$VC compiler tries to use this where possibly. I would also follow this convention, it will keep me having only one instruction in a loop modifying flag - and that is the counter right bottom.. yes you re right about MOP fusion