# How to extract data from xmm register by index stored in another register r10 to store that dword in eax?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, sse, avx

I need to extract dword from XMM1, which is located at index, stored in R10, and move it to EAX register.
How to do that efficiently, not involving memory access?

Following would not compile:
PEXTRD  EAX,XMM1,R10d

Comment: There is no instruction to do it directly. And none of the alternatives are likely to be better than going through memory.

Comment: Mysticial Very sad. I am looking for a ways to offload memory while multiplexing streams in logic emulator, in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372852/how-to-optimise-double-dereferencing

Comment: Gather instructions might be useful for your use case. But they are also very slow. Fundamentally, anything with non-linear memory access will be slow since it's inherently difficult to implement in hardware.

Comment: Mysticial, loop unrolling and prefetch instructions helped abit ~10% performance gain